# RegEx: comma-separated list of pairs

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of comma-separated "pairs", like so:

```
<0,64000><1,207><2,460b0><3,38000><4,460b0><5,38000><6,460b0><7,38000><8,460b0><9,38000><a,460b0>
```

Each value is in hex. I'm using the following regex to capture each pair (in Python)

`\<[^\>]*\>`

This works as I get `<0,64000>` as the first match, `<1,207>` as the second, and so on.

As I'm interested in the values, I'm trying to be lazy and avoid manipulating the resulting match to remove `<` and `>`, so I did:

`\<([^\>]*)\>`

Now each capture group is `0,64000`, `1,207`. I'd like to go one step further and try to capture each number instead of the pair. Any ideas on how I do this with a single regex?

Much thanks!!

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'<([\da-f]+),([\da-f]+)>', text, re.I)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the simplest example, you can use this:

```
<([^,]+),([^>]+)>
```

This captures everything after the first `<` but before the comma as the first value, and everything that doesn't contain a `>` as the second one. You could also specify that these values must be hex:

```
<([0-9a-f]+),([0-9a-f]+)>
```

Comment: OMG, so simple! OK, it's Monday, I'm a little slow today. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1):

If you use PyPi `regex`:

```py
import regex
string = "<0,64000><1,207><2,460b0><3,38000><4,460b0><5,38000><6,460b0><7,38000><8,460b0><9,38000><a,460b0>"
print(regex.findall(r'<([[:xdigit:]]+),([[:xdigit:]]+)>', string))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##Xc6xDoIwGATgnadoWGjjH1NpLUhqX4QwYEBsgqWpHfDpK0H/xfG@G@78Oz4WJ1KyT7@ESMI4jWv2isG6iVxJrjkoyTk3@gQlr4wuQSp@27IAUe@FRDmjKJQKpUa5oPQ/yTO/bUW6Dx/v1g39PNNQaNq2zTrYycam6w4M/rIpgHxvMpbSBw). `[[:xdigit:]]+` = `[0-9A-Fa-f]+`. So, it is equal to

```py
regex.findall(r'<([0-9A-Fa-f]+),([0-9A-Fa-f]+)>', string)
```

**Results**: `[('0', '64000'), ('1', '207'), ('2', '460b0'), ('3', '38000'), ('4', '460b0'), ('5', '38000'), ('6', '460b0'), ('7', '38000'), ('8', '460b0'), ('9', '38000'), ('a', '460b0')]`

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [[:xdigit:]]+            any character of: hexadecimal digits (a-
                             f, A-F, 0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [[:xdigit:]]+            any character of: hexadecimal digits (a-
                             f, A-F, 0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
```